# How can we query Kibana?

Tags: api, rest, elasticsearch, kibana

How can we request Kibana with REST API to get the visualization request
and response?

Like this:
[image: screenshot]

I want to do that using NodeJS to manipulate this results of Kibana.
The purpose is that I want to directly query Kibana programmatically (via REST API) to get the ES request body.

Comment: ** I want to directly query Kibana programmatically (via REST API) to get the ES request body.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. There is a .kibana index, this does contain the configuration of the dashboard. But I do not see the actual query that is performed in there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can directly request the ES. The documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html)

Comment: thank you for your response, but i would like to know if there is a way to query kibana

Comment: You can do that but it's not the purpose of Kibana. This tool is just a visualization tool. So If you want to try it, you can see the request that kibana does (F12 on your browser).

Comment: I can see the request in kibana , under the graph but can we call it  programmatically ?

Comment: As I said before, I think the best way to get response from ES is to call the ES API. You can do that with the JAVA API : [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html)

Comment: kibana gives heap size, request per second.. like that parameters. I want to implement dash board using these data.Is the rest api that gives these data from kibana

Comment: hey @Nader, if you got the solution to query Kibana from JAVA then pls share it.As I also need the same

Comment: If I query ES for a field equal to a given value and I get the response then how can change the kibana graph from that response on my webpage ?

Comment: I just want to use kibana for a front end i dont want to hit api of elasticsearc rather i want to hit on other api can we do it ?

Comment: My issue is Kibana front-end is exposed for me to access but the backing ES endpoint is not. I want to avoid using UI Automation to pull logs for validation test steps. Most of my tests are using SoapUI so a REST plugin would be best... but a simplified HTTP(s) request would also work. (FYI the Kibana/dev_tools/console is currently disabled :-( .)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to kibana\kibana-4.5.1-windows\optimize\bundles\kibana.bundle.js file,
search the function "Transport.prototype.request = function (params, cb)",
and add in the first line `parent.postMessage(params.body, "*");`
Now go to the controller or script that manage the iframe(iframe parent)
and add

```
$window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {          
              var data=event.data;          
            });
```

for example:

```
    <iframe id="ifr" src="http://localhost:5601/goto/6ba8a6b8ceef3tyt454789e4fe5cf5"></iframe>

    <script>
        $window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {          
          var data=event.data;          
        });
    </script
```

Now you will get the request query