# Is there a way to communicate between a Kibana dashboard and its parent frame?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Let's say I have a Kibana Dashboard. The dashboard shows a bar plot. I embed the dashboard as an iframe into a parent application. The user clicks a category in the bar plot. I want the parent frame to respond in some way.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Does Kibana issue any calls to postMessage() that I could intercept to determine when certain events occur within the dashboard? Do any plugins exist that implement this functionality?

I see certain references to postMessage() when I inspect the Kibana dashboard, but it appears this may be limited to an underlying library using web workers. I don't see any documentation surrounding the subject, but I want to know if this functionality is possible, even if only through hacks or plugins.

Comment: as far as i know such thing is not intended in kibana, so you need to be hacky to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also searched plugin for this but didn't find so I did it with hack.
The embed iframe contain kibana scripts.

1)you need to add one line in kibana.bundle.js file code, this line will notify you about the kibana request when the user click on the chart.

2)you need to add one line code in your app script, this line will handler the previus request.

you can see my answer in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827222/how-can-we-query-kibana/38366284#38366284)

if something unclear, please ask again

Comment: My involvement with the project ended a while back, but I will mark this as the answer since it would accomplish the task at hand.